# Do I need to disable AWE in SQL Server 2000 if I need the memory for something else?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, awe

I've got a SQL 2000 installation on which I've enabled AWE to address additional memory. I'm in the process of migrating to SQL 2005 and the majority of the memory will now be needed for the 2005 instance. Can I leave 2000 with AWE set up, or should I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper thing to do would be to adjust the **max server memory** setting to a lower limit.

Also, Task manager will not show the correct amount of memory allocated to sql server. Use [DBCC MEMORYSTATUS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271624) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Seems not,

I've restarted the service and it's sitting on a pretty puny amount of memory.

Comment: Is the 2005 instance on the same box as the 2000 instance? How big are your databases?